# Getting "error"=>"Array" array response from python JSON server and PHP client

Tags: php, python, json, client, rpc

I've written a simple JSON RPC server in python as an interface to a python program. The server works fine when I use curl to to manually construct JSON requests from it. When I use the JSON library from here: http://jsonrpcphp.org/ I just get an error response "Array" in return.

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, because I've tested the server and it works when I don't use the PHP library.

I've check and the content type is set to "application/json".

Heres the PHP code:

```
$server= new jsonRPCClient("http://$serveraddress:$port");


try {
    echo($server->do_stop());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "caught exception: ", $e->getMessage() ,"<br />";
}
```

EDIT:

Here's a print_r of the $server object (localhost should have http://  before it but I can't Put it in):

```
jsonRPCClient Object ( [debug:jsonRPCClient:private] => [url:jsonRPCClient:private] => localhost:3000[id:jsonRPCClient:private] => 1 [notification:jsonRPCClient:private] => [proxy] => )
```

do_stop() just raises an exception 
    "Request Error: Array"

EDIT2:
Solved the rpoblem, turns out that I was requesting an incorrect method. I forgot that I changed the name to stop().

Logic errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

construct ur object setting the debug flag to true

```
 $server= new jsonRPCClient("http://$serveraddress:$port", true);
```

reading the [source code](http://jsonrpcphp.org/code.php?file=jsonRPCClient) of the json rpc client, seems like the error is coming from ur server:

```
    // final checks and return
    if (!$this->notification) {
        // check
        if ($response['id'] != $currentId) {
            throw new Exception('Incorrect response id (request id: '.$currentId.', response id: '.$response['id'].')');
        }
        if (!is_null($response['error'])) {
            throw new Exception('Request error: '.$response['error']);
        }

        return $response['result'];

    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: When I looked throuch the code I found the same thing. Could it be that the reuest is somehow wrong which causes the server to return the error?
I have tested the server and it works fine when not using PHP.

Comment: inspect the request in the python server? check whats the difference in the requests between curl and json-rpc. you can paste some server code/debug infor from the server in the question.